# counting a permutation 4 characters long with 2 characters on each result

Tags: python, permutation

```
from itertools import permutations
perm=permutations(['A','B','C','C','D','D','D','D'],4)
for i in perm:
  print (i)
```

how could I print a permutation of which the value in perm only prints a series of letters with 2 characters (pardon my English)

example : ADDD,DADD,BDDD,CCDD,CDDD etc (only 2 characters for every permutation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this you will have to generate all combinations, and filter down to the condition you want.

Keep this bit the same:

```
from itertools import permutations
perm = permutations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 4)
```

But then keep only the elements which satisfy your condition, by using list comprehension. Convert the element to a set, and count the length of the set. An element like ('A', 'B', 'B') gets converted to {'A', 'B'}.

```
perm = [x for x in perm if len(set(x))==2]
```

Comment: thank you, this works wonderfully. but the amount it prints is 528 combinations. now, how can I make it down to 18?

Comment: If you only want 18, then just take the first 18. Or is there some other constraint you didn’t mention in your question?

Comment: the constraint is that if a combination is already present, then if there's any similar combination, it shall not be printed/counted (no duplicates are allowed)

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in perm:
    if len((set(list(i))) == 2:
       print (i)
```

lets say i is ABAA
list(i) will result in [A,B,A,A]
set() of that will result in {A,B}
then len() of that will be 2